# php - using JOIN sql query in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, while-loop

I have this query:

```
    $r = $dbh->prepare("
            SELECT ur.user, urs.*
            FROM xeon_users_rented as ur 
              JOIN xeon_users_rented_stats as urs ON ur.user_by=urs.urs_user 
            WHERE ur.user_by=:user 
            "
    );
    $r->bindParam(':user', $userdata['username']);
    $r->execute();
```

Which I am looping:

```
while($referralData=$r->fetch()):

echo $referralData['id'];

endwhile;
```

My problem is, that the loop doesn't run. If I place anything inside the loop, is it not shown.

The original query (without JOIN) looks like this:

```
$r = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM xeon_users_rented WHERE user_by=:user");
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do a var_dump($->fetch()) to us!

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly in your database to verify that you're getting the result you expect?

Comment: @jeroen the loop isn't entered. (Edited my question, sorry)

Comment: Run the query directly in your database as @MattBrowne mentioned, the query probably isn't returning anything.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I have included the original query (without JOIN function) Maybe that can help.

Comment: what are all of you columns in both tables?

Comment: Does your user exist in both tables?

Comment: @Rickkwa in xeon_users_rented it does. (user_by field) in the other, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user needs to exist in both tables.

When you join `xeon_users_rented` and `xeon_users_rented_stats` on `ur.user_by=urs.urs_user`, it means that you will combine the rows from both the tables when `ur.user_by=urs.urs_user`. So the combined row will both have the same user. Since your user only exists in 1 table, when joining, the row in `xeon_users_rented` with your user cannot find a row in the other table to combine with since the other table doesn't have the user.

For example:

TableA

```
user      age
------------------
john      20
ricky     24
paul      30
```

TableB

```
user      someStat
------------------
john      100
paul      200
paul      300
```

If we join TableA with TableB on TableA.user = TableB.user, we'll get

```
TableA.user     TableA.age    TableB.user    TableB.someStat
---------------------------------------------------------------
john            20            john           100
paul            30            paul           200
paul            30            paul           300
```

For every row in TableA, it will find all rows in TableB with the same user and combine the rows in the resulting table. Since Ricky is not in TableB, he is not in the results.

Now if we do a `LEFT JOIN`, this guarantees all the rows for the table on the left side of the join (TableA in this case), and will fill in data on the right side where available.

```
TableA.user     TableA.age    TableB.user    TableB.someStat
--------------------------------------------------------------
john            20            john           100
ricky           24            NULL           NULL
paul            30            paul           200
paul            30            paul           300
```

Now the result includes Ricky, but since Ricky is not in TableB, the columns corresponding to TableB are filled with NULLs

Comment: Is there anyway I can use the join function, if the user doesn't exist in the other table? (xeon_users_rented_stats) 
It only exist in some cases.

Comment: Say it exists in `rented` but not in `rented_stats`. What do you expect to see in the result?

Comment: I expected to see records from "rented" in the loop. And it it existed in "rented_stats", then I would be able to use those records.

Comment: Try using a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I am very new to the JOIN functions, care to show an example?

Comment: @Rickwwa Thank you so much! It's a hard subject, but your explanation really helped clearing a few things.

Comment: @oliverbj For more information on joins, check out this very popular article which really does a great job of explaining how joins work - http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/